# Jenkins Build Pipeline Plugin - Blank White modal window - no parameter prompt issue on first job

Tags: jenkins, parameters, modal-dialog, jenkins-plugins, build-pipeline-plugin

Jenkins 1.573 / 1.628 or latest version.
Build Pipeline plugin : 1.4.8 (latest)

Till last week everything was OK, today I'm seeing that when I click on the first job in the Build Pipeline dashboard view (to run a process), it used to prompt parameters but not anymore. It's giving me a BLANK white modal window / popup page and there are no input parameters visible.

Any idea! what I may be missing.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=03793493629898722609&t=0379349362989872260930671

[image: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03793493629898722609]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

The issue is either with the Build Pipeline plugin (not using / compatible with Chrome browser) OR it's a Chrome browser issue.

I somehow had Chrome session opened the other day and when I click on "Run" (top section) to start the pipeline / job run, it shows me a BLANK modal window and doesn't show me any parameters.

**Version 46.0.2490.86 m**

*Google Chrome is up to date.*

While the same is working in IE or Firefox (I have the latest versions). I guess, I'll use FF/IE for now.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but solution was different. In my Jenkins configuration, the Jenkins URL was not set correctly - it was a http address, whereas my Jenkins was set up with TLS. So make sure that Manage Jenkins - Configure System - Jenkins URL is set correctly.